# How does porting between Linux and Windows work?

Tags: windows, linux, porting

If a particular piece of software is made to be run on one platform and the programmer/company/whatever wants to port it to the other, what exactly is done? I mean, do they just rewrite linux or windows-specific references to the equivalent in the other? Or is an entire rewrite necessary?

Just trying to understand what makes it so cost-prohibitive that so many major vendors don't port their software to Linux (specifically thinking about Adobe)

Thanks

Comment: The answer is not always about cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the point of a cross-platform toolkit like qt or gtk, they provide a platform-agnostic API, which delegates to whichever platform the program is compiled for.

some companies don't use such a toolkit, and write their own (for whatever reason - could well be optimisation-related), meaning they can't just recompile their code for another os.

Answer (score 3):

There are also libraries available that ease, at least on a specific area, the port of Windows API calls to Linux.  See the [Windows to Linux porting library](http://www.adontec.com/windows-to-linux-port-library.htm).

Comment: `w2lpl.h` is a commercial product. a "single developer license" costs 290 EUR

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there are three main reasons why it's cost-prohibitive to take a large existing program on one platform and port it to another:

1. it has (not necessarily purposely) extensively used some library or API (often GUI, but there are also plenty of other things) that turns out not to exist on the other platform
2. it has unknowingly become riddled with dependency on nonstandard features or oddities of the compiler or other tools
3. it was written by somebody who didn't know that you *had* to use some oddball feature to get things to work on the other platform (like a Linux library that isn't sprinkled with the right `__declspec` directives you need for a good Windows DLL).

It's much easier to write a cross-platform app if you consider that a design goal from the start, and I have three specific recommendations:

- Use Boost—oodles of handy things you might ordinarily get from platform-specific APIs and libraries, but by using Boost you get it cross-platform.
- Do all your GUI programming using a cross-platform library.  My favorite these days is Qt, but there are other worthy ones as well.
- Build and test **every day** on both platforms, never provide an opportunity for the code to develop a dependency on only one platform and discover it only too late.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why it may be very difficult to port an application to a different platform, most often it is because some interfaces the application uses to communicate with the system are not available, and one either has to implement them on their own, port a library your application depends on, or rewrite the application, so that it uses alternative functions. Most languages today are very portable across hardware architectures and operating systems, but the problem is with libraries, system calls and potentially other interfaces the OS (or platform) provides. To be more specific:

- Compilers may differ in their configuration and the standard functions they provide. On Windows the most popular compiler for C/C++ is Visual Studio, while on unix it is gcc and llvm (in combination with the standard library glibc or BSD libc). They expect different flags, different forms of declaration, produce different file format of executables and shared libraries. Even though C and C++ have standard libraries, they are implemented differently across platforms. There are some systems whose aim is to make compilation portable, such as Autotools, CMake and SCons.
- On top of standard libraries there are additional functions OS provides. On Windows they are covered by win32 API, on unix systems these are part of the POSIX standard, with various GNU, BSD and Linux specific extensions, and there are also plain system calls (the lowest-level interface between applications and the operating system). POSIX functions are available on Windows via systems such as cygwin and mingw, win32 API function are available on unix via Wine. The problem is that these implementations are not complete, and often there are minor (but important) differences.
- Communication with the desktop system (in order to make a GUI interface) is done differently. On Linux this might be the X Window System (together with freedesktop libraries) or Wayland, while Windows has its own systems. There are GUI libraries which try to provide an abstract interface for these, such as Qt, GTK, wxWidgets, EFL.
- Other services the OS provides, such as network communication may be implemented differently. On Windows many applications use .NET libraries, for which there is only limited support on unix systems. Some unix applications rely on Linux-specific features such as systemd, /proc, KMS, cgroups, namespaces. This limits portability even among unix systems (Linux, BSD systems, Mac OS X, ...). Even .NET libraries are not very compatible across different versions, and they might not be available on an older version of Windows or on embedded systems. Android and iOS have different interfaces entirely.
- Web applications are usually the most portable, but HTML5 is a live standard, and many interfaces may not be available yet in some browsers/web engines. This requires the use of polyfills, but it is usually much less painful than the situation with "native" applications.

Because of all of these limitations, porting can be a pretty hard work and sometimes it is easier to create a new application from scratch, either specifically for the other platform, using cross-platform abstraction libraries/platforms (such as Qt or Java), or as a web application (potentially bundled in something like Electron). It is a good idea to use these from the beginning, but many programmers choose not to because the applications tend to look and behave differently from "native" applications on the platform, and they might also be slower and more restricted in the way they interact with the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Porting a piece of software that has not been made platform-independant upfront can be an enormous task. Often, the code is deeply ingrained with non-portable APIs, whether 3rd party or just OS libraries. If the 3rd party vendor does not provide the API for the platform you are porting on, you are pretty much forced into a full rewrite of that functionality, or finding another 3rd party that is portable. This only can be awfully costly.

Finally, porting software also means supporting it on another platform, which means hiring some specialists, and training support to answer more complex queries.

In the end, such a process can be very costly, for very little additional sales. Sadly, the decision is easy: concentrate on new functionality on your current platform that you know your customers are going to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

If the software was written for a single OS, a major rework is likely. The first step is to move absolutely all platform-specific code into a single area of the code base; this area should have little or no app-specific stuff. Then rewrite this isolated portion of the code for the new target OS.

Of course, this glosses over some extremely major implications. For instance, if your first version targeted the Win32 API, then any GUI code will be heavily tied to Windows, and to maintain any hope of preserving your sanity, you will need to move all that code to a cross-platform GUI framework like Qt or GTK.

Answer (score 0):

Under Mono, you can write a C# Winforms program that works on both platforms.  But to make that possible, the Mono team had to write their own Winforms library that essentially duplicates all of the functions of Winforms.  So there is still no free lunch.

Answer (score 0):

Most software is portable to some extent. In the case of a C app - there will be a lot of #ifdefs in the area, apart from path changes, etc.

Rarely windows/linux version of the same software don't share a common codebase - this would actually mean that they only share a common name. It's always harder to maintain more codebases, but I think that the actual problem with porting applications has little to do with the technical side and a lot with business side. Linux has much fewer users that Windows/OSX, most of them expect everything to be free as in beer or simply hate commercial software on some religious grounds.

When you come to think about it - most open source software is multiplatform, no matter what language was used to implement it. This speaks for itself...

P.S. Disclaimer - I'm an avid supporter of Free and Open source software, I don't want to insult anybody - I just share my perspective on the topic.