# If stdio is cross-platform C / standard library abstraction for C

Tags: c, cross-platform

I am looking at compiling C for cross-platform, and have that figured out. Now I am wondering if you need libraries specific to windows/mac/linux, or if `stdio` (glibc) is a cross-platform library that abstracts away all the low-level syscalls into a nice standard API. Not sure if it's doing that. For example, file-system stuff, seems like that is cross-platform. But maybe net connection stuff isn't, not sure. Also, I see [here](https://github.com/jwerle/fs.c/blob/95e508f71348d2dce43d45a86867775ff1591525/fs.c#L113) a lot of `#ifdef _WIN32`, even though it is just a simple file-system wrapper over `stdio`, so not sure if stdio is not covering everything.

Looking around a bit I see some "cross-platform" libraries like [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/tree/27ba66281199bdcade823677af8dedc161152fb6/src) have code specific to windows vs. unix, so not sure if there are cases where you need to hook into "native" (os-specific) functionality, and when/where you typically need to do that.

Wondering first if glibc / stdio is a cross-platform abstraction around the syscalls and common other functions. Then wondering if one could explain/outline briefly when you need to write platform-specific functionality, and if there is not a standard library / abstraction on top of that.

Comment: stdio.h is fully portable. glibc is an open source implementation of stdio.h (along other things) for certain systems. So are you asking if stdio.h is portable or if glibc is portable? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdio.h`  is part of the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf); you really should download and read that). If you restrict yourself to use only functions described by that standard (in the way that standard specifies), and if you use standard conforming implementations (e.g. compilers and C standard library implementations), you should be safe.

However, many features (e.g. directories, symbolic links, file truncation) are *outside* of the C11 standard. You might be interested by the POSIX standard.

[Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) are *not* part of the C11 standard (but mostly POSIX, see [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)).

Some libraries (e.g. [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)) try to define common abstractions for several OSes. You might consider these if you want to easily write source code compilable on several common platforms. (With C++ you could also use [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [Boost](http://boost.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), ....)

BTW, Linux man pages (start with [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html)...) often mention the standard followed by most functions. For example [chown(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html) is defined in  POSIX.1-2008.

Notice also that standards are specifications, which might not be entirely followed or respected (and they are bugs even in standards). For example C11 [threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) (e.g. `thrd_create`) might not be available in some (still used) versions of [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (because it has [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) which predated C11). Also, some libraries implement standard functions beyond what the standard requires (e.g. on Linux [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) understands `m` in the mode string).

Remember the maxim: there is no portable code, only code that has been ported (to some *specific* system[s]). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2664254/841108).

Comment: For those interested in POSIX (also known as IEEE Std 1003.1™), the 2018 version is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). For C programmers, the *Base Definitions* and *System Interfaces* contain the salient parts.